# Unable to find numeric literal operator 'operator""+BLA'

Tags: c++, operators, literals, preprocessor

I had this:

```
#define BLA 10
#define BLABLA (0x3E+BLA)
```

And I am getting:

> error: unable to find numeric literal operator 'operator""+BLA'

---

Example code:

```
#define BLA 10
#define BLABLA (0x3E+BLA)

int main()
{
    return BLABLA;
}
```

Compile line (g++ Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9):

```
g++ example.cpp -o example
```

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce this problem in C++98 or C++11.

Answer (score 1):

Replacing the second line with this (ie, adding spaces) made it happy:

```
#define BLABLA (0x3E + BLA)
```